# Spring MVC process post data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC app. This application expects the client to send a XML in the request body. How can I extract this XML from the body and then create a DOM object?
I am using Spring 3.0

Thanks
Adi

Answer (score 2):

Using the [@RequestBody annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestbody):

> The @RequestBody method parameter annotation indicates that a method
>   parameter should be bound to the value of the HTTP request body. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
> public void handle(@RequestBody String body, Writer writer) throws IOException 
>     writer.write(body);
> }
> ```
>
> You convert the request body to the method argument by using an
>   HttpMessageConverter. HttpMessageConverter is responsible for
>   converting from the HTTP request message to an object and converting
>   from an object to the HTTP response body. The
>   RequestMappingHandlerAdapter supports the @RequestBody annotation with
>   the following default HttpMessageConverters:
>
> ```
> ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter converts byte arrays.
>
> StringHttpMessageConverter converts strings.
>
> FormHttpMessageConverter converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap<String, String>.
>
> SourceHttpMessageConverter converts to/from a javax.xml.transform.Source.
> ```

Comment: So the body argument will contain the XML? and I can just using SourceHttpMessageConverter to get the DOM out of it?